# change opencart to woocommerce manually

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, opencart

There's a client that ask me to import a database from opencart to a wordpress woocommerce website

I know there is an automated migration, but I would like to change it manually

So I thought of changing the opencart database to a csv file, then I just upload it to the wordpress woocommerce, is this method possible? if not, can someone tell me how to manually change from opencart database to woocommerce, thank you in advance

Comment: It is almost impossible. OpenCart have Custom Options product but WooCommerce only support Product Variants, you can not generate the Variants from the Options manually. The best way is to hire a **Shopping Cart Migration Service**. You could try this one: [WooCommerce Migration Service](https://next-cart.com/supported-carts/woocommerce/)

Answer (score 1):

I don't think is the best solution to migrate manually Opencart database to Woocommerce because you can skip something in the migration process and the risk to not solve this it higher. Woocommerce is coded differently, uses different tables, and also it uses InnoDB (unlike OpenCart which uses MyISAM). If you have no idea how to manually migrate your data, you will either need to look for a migration tool to do it for you. Also you can check with your hosting provider because could offer a migration service as well. Are some tutorials from where you can start https://www.wpglobalsupport.com/migrate-data-from-opencart-to-woocommerce/ and a module that can help you https://www.opencart.com/index.php?route=marketplace/extension/info&extension_id=17&filter_search=export&filter_license=0&filter_download_id=55